# How to switch Google Japanese keyboard to romaji input instead of hiragana?

Tags: google-japanese-input

I just got a new phone so I had to reinstall my Japanese IME and it has a kana layout kinda like a flip phone too. I heard that the Google IME will let you use romaji input like a regular keyboard, but how do I switch it?

Answer (score 3):

Google Japanese Input currently supports 3 layouts:

- 12 keys: Mobile phone layout
- QWERTY: PC keyboard layout
- Godan keyboard: Romaji-dedicated layout

You can change it from **Settings - Language & input - Google Japanese Input - Keyboard layout**.

Answer (score 0):

I hear you. It is super simple to switch from Hiragana to Romaji.

1. Go into Settings
2. Go into Language and input
3. Go into Google Japanese Input
4. Go into Keyboard Layout.
5. Use these settings to switch the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

May I assume that you know how to read the 5x10 kana array?

If so, leave the 22-key layout as is (for Japanese anyway) and learn how to use "flick input." The keys are bigger, and there's less motion than using all those CV and CCV combinations.

Taking the 2 key, for example:

- Tap the key for か
- Flick left for き
- Flick up for く
- Flick right for け
- Flick down for こ

Converting the hiragana into kanji whatever is as before.

When switching to English, there are two buttons for returning to your QWERTY layout: the globe and ABC.

https://files.tofugu.com/articles/japanese/2016-04-18-how-to-install-japanese-keyboard/android-typing-ku.jpg